# Handling Facebook response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've got this code to handle Facebook response:

```
if (response && !response.error_message) {
                            alert('Posting completed with Post ID:' + response.post_id);
                            FB.api( '/' + response.post_id, function( response ) {
                                x$().xhr('<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('survey/saveSocialMediaPost', array('answer_id'=>$answer->id, 'social_network'=>1)); ?>', {
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    async: true,
                                    meta: response,
                                });
                                console.log( response );
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert('Error while posting.');
                        }
                    }
```

As you can see, after a right post what I want to do is call an ajax to do some actions in my database. The problem here is that I don't know how to handle the response. console.log(response) throws something like that:

```
Object { created_time: "2016-03-05T01:27:27+0000", message: "Prueba de comentarios.", id: "xxxxxx_xxxxx" }
```

Exactly what I need to get is `message`. id is solved with response.post_id.

Comment: what do you want to achieve, and what want to save from response to DB?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
console.log(response.message);
```

It´s a simple JSON object, you should get familiar with JSON - it´s very important in the JavaScript world.